# Currently lost at using JSON parse

Tags: json

I'm currently lost at using JSON parses. Not sure if beginner's mistake or there's some rules that I'm currently breaking.

HTML:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="button" name="hub">PC Hub</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="button" name="dquest">DynaquestPC</button>
</form>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>CPU</td>
      <td>
         <p id="1800xName"></p>
      </td>
      <td id="alignRight">
         <p id="1800xPrice"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>CPU Cooler</td>
      <td>
         <p id="CoolerName"></p>
      </td>
      <td id="alignRight">
         <p id="CoolerPrice"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>RAM</td>
      <td>
         <p id="4x4Name"></p>
      </td>
      <td id="alignRight">
         <p id="4x4Price"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>SSD</td>
      <td>
         <p id="EvoName"></p>
      </td>
      <td id="alignRight">
         <p id="EvoPrice"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>HDD</td>
      <td>
         <p id="WDBName"></p>
      </td>
      <td id="alignRight">
         <p id="WDBPrice"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Power Supply</td>
      <td>
         <p id="M12Name"></p>
      </td>
      <td id="alignRight">
         <p id="M12Price"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var CPUs = '{"CPU": [' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 7 1800X","Price":27000 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 7 1700X","Price":20700 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 7 1700","Price":17000 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1600X","Price":12770 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1600","Price":11120 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1500X","Price":9780 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1400","Price":8650 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 3 1300X","Price":7340 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 3 1200","Price":6230 },' +

   '{"Name":"Ryzen 7 1800X","Price":27000 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 7 1700X","Price":20700 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 7 1700","Price":17000 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1600X","Price":12770 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1600","Price":11150 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1500X","Price":9780 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 5 1400","Price":8650 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 3 1300X","Price":0 },' +
   '{"Name":"Ryzen 3 1200","Price":0 }]}';
cpuData = JSON.parse(CPUs);

var CPUCooler = '{"Cooler": [' +
   '{"Name":"Cryorig H7","Price":1900 },' +
   '{"Name":"Cooler Master Hyper 212","Price":1850 }]}';
coolerData = JSON.parse(CPUCooler);

var RAM = '{"RAM": [' +
   '{"Name":"4x4GB GSkill Ripjaws 2666MHz","Price":7970 },' +
   '{"Name":"2x4GB Kingston HyperX Fury 2400MHz","Price":4060 },' +

   '{"Name":"4x4 Corsair Vengeance LPX 2800MHz","Price":7650 },' +
   '{"Name":"2x4 GSkill Ripjaws V 2800MHz","Price":4090 }]}';
ramData = JSON.parse(RAM);

var ssd = '{"SSD": [' +
   '{"Name":"Samsung 850 EVO 250GB","Price":4740 },' +
   '{"Name":"Western Digital Green 120GB","Price":2890 },' +

   '{"Name":"Samsung 850 EVO 250GB","Price":4900 },' +
   '{"Name":"Western Digital Green 120GB","Price":2900 }]}';
ssdData = JSON.parse(ssd);

var hdd = '{"HDD": [' +
   '{"Name":"WD Caviar Blue 1TB","Price":2350 },' +
   '{"Name":"Seagate Skyhawk 1TB","Price":2640 },' +

   '{"Name":"WD Caviar Blue 1TB","Price":2350 },' +
   '{"Name":"Seagate Barracuda 1TB","Price":2490 }]}';
hddData = JSON.parse(hdd);

var psu = '{"PSU": [' +
   '{"Name":"Seasonic G550","Price":4170 },' +
   '{"Name":"Seasonic M12ii-520","Price":3460 },' +
   '{"Name":"Seasonic S12ii-520","Price":2780 },' +

   '{"Name":"Seasonic G550","Price":4350 },' +
   '{"Name":"Seasonic M12ii-520","Price":3350 },' +
   '{"Name":"Seasonic S12ii-520","Price":2850 }]}';
psuData = JSON.parse(psu);

document.getElementsByName("hub")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("1800xName").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[0].Name;
   document.getElementById("1800xPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[0].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1700xName").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[1].Name;
   document.getElementById("1700xPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[1].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1700Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[2].Name;
   document.getElementById("1700Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[2].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1600Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[3].Name;
   document.getElementById("1600Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[3].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1600Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[4].Name;
   document.getElementById("1600Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[4].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1500xName").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[5].Name;
   document.getElementById("1500xPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[5].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1400Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[6].Name;
   document.getElementById("1400Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[6].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("CoolerName").innerHTML = coolerData.Cooler[0].Name;
   document.getElementById("CoolerPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(coolerData.Cooler[0].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("4x4Name").innerHTML = ramData.RAM[0].Name;
   document.getElementById("4x4Price").innerHTML = parseInt(ramData.RAM[0].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("2x4Name").innerHTML = ramData.RAM[1].Name;
   document.getElementById("2x4Price").innerHTML = parseInt(ramData.RAM[1].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("EvoName").innerHTML = ssdData.SSD[0].Name;
   document.getElementById("EvoPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(ssdData.SSD[0].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("WDGName").innerHTML = ssdData.SSD[1].Name;
   document.getElementById("WDGPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(ssdData.SSD[1].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("WDBName").innerHTML = hddData.HDD[0].Name;
   document.getElementById("WDBPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(hddData.HDD[0].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("SeaName").innerHTML = hddData.HDD[1].Name;
   document.getElementById("SeaPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(hddData.HDD[1].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("G550Name").innerHTML = psuData.PSU[0].Name;
   document.getElementById("G550Price").innerHTML = parseInt(psuData.PSU[0].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("M12Name").innerHTML = psuData.PSU[1].Name;
   document.getElementById("M12Price").innerHTML = parseInt(psuData.PSU[1].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("S12Name").innerHTML = psuData.PSU[2].Name;
   document.getElementById("S12Price").innerHTML = parseInt(psuData.PSU[2].Price).toLocaleString();
});

document.getElementsByName("dquest")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("1800xName").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[9].Name;
   document.getElementById("1800xPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[9].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1700xName").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[10].Name;
   document.getElementById("1700xPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[10].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1700Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[11].Name;
   document.getElementById("1700Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[11].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1600Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[12].Name;
   document.getElementById("1600Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[12].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1500xName").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[13].Name;
   document.getElementById("1500xPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[13].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("1400Name").innerHTML = cpuData.CPU[14].Name;
   document.getElementById("1400Price").innerHTML = parseInt(cpuData.CPU[14].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("CoolerName").innerHTML = coolerData.Cooler[1].Name;
   document.getElementById("CoolerPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(coolerData.Cooler[1].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("4x4Name").innerHTML = ramData.RAM[2].Name;
   document.getElementById("4x4Price").innerHTML = parseInt(ramData.RAM[2].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("2x4Name").innerHTML = ramData.RAM[3].Name;
   document.getElementById("2x4Price").innerHTML = parseInt(ramData.RAM[3].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("EvoName").innerHTML = ssdData.SSD[2].Name;
   document.getElementById("EvoPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(ssdData.SSD[2].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("WDGName").innerHTML = ssdData.SSD[3].Name;
   document.getElementById("WDGPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(ssdData.SSD[3].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("WDBName").innerHTML = hddData.HDD[2].Name;
   document.getElementById("WDBPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(hddData.HDD[2].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("SeaName").innerHTML = hddData.HDD[3].Name;
   document.getElementById("SeaPrice").innerHTML = parseInt(hddData.HDD[3].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("G550Name").innerHTML = psuData.PSU[3].Name;
   document.getElementById("G550Price").innerHTML = parseInt(psuData.PSU[3].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("M12Name").innerHTML = psuData.PSU[4].Name;
   document.getElementById("M12Price").innerHTML = parseInt(psuData.PSU[4].Price).toLocaleString();

   document.getElementById("S12Name").innerHTML = psuData.PSU[5].Name;
   document.getElementById("S12Price").innerHTML = parseInt(psuData.PSU[5].Price).toLocaleString();
});
```

I also can't seem to find the error code since it is a webpage. Anyone know how to fix? Pretty lost right now

Comment: Post the code and error message in the question itself. No links

Comment: added. can't find error message in webpage

Comment: You should be able to access error messages in most modern browsers by opening that browsers developer tool kit. Once you have that open, refresh your site and any javascript errors will appear in the console. Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools. Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox. Edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide